# Question about algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ideals, algebras

I have a question from Folland's book "Real Analysis" (p. 142. ex. 71. c)

Let $X$ be compact and Hausdorff space and $M$ be the set of all nonzero algebra homomorphisms from $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is set of continuous functions from $X$ to the real line. Each $x$ in $X$ defines an element $y$ of $M$, by $y(f) = f(x)$.

The question is that prove that the map $x \mapsto y$ is a bijection from $X$ to $M$. Maybe its' easy to prove that its injective, but I can`t prove surjectivity.
Also in same problem I proved that if $Q$ is the proper ideal in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$, then there exists $z$ in $X$, such that $f(z)=0$ for all $f$ in $Q$. But I am not sure that this fact can used in my question.

Comment: The fact about proper ideals that you mentioned is very important! Use this to classify the maximal ideals of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$, which will then let you classify the algebra homomorphisms in question.

Comment: Yes, I prove that for any h from M, maximal proper ideal of C(X,R) is a family of f functions such that h(f)=0, but after this I cant think what I should do.

Comment: What's the relationship between maximal ideals and homomorphisms to $\mathbb{R}$? Hint: use the first isomorphism theorem

Comment: Do you mean the fact that image of maximal ideal is {0} or there is any other useful fact? I am studying general topology and unfortunetely, for this time, not familiar with algebrai structures. Sorry for my beginner questions

Comment: Yes, the only ideals of $\Bbb{R}$ are $(0)$ and $\Bbb{R}$ itself (this is because the reals form a field). Use this together with the first isomorphism theorem.